# PHP - exec C++ with parameters

Tags: php, c++, parameters

I'm trying to implement a program which recuperate picture and width of picture in order to send to process in c++ program.
I have no problem to recuperate these items in php code.
The problem is when I send this variables in my php exec function. I have tried a lot of thing without results. Thank you in advance for your reply.
Herebelow, my last code in php :

```
/* Stock picture to verify there is no problem */
$image=$_REQUEST['image'];
$binary=base64_decode($image);
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$file = fopen('test.jpg', 'wb'); 
fwrite($file, $binary); 
fclose($file); 

/* We recuperate the width of the picture */
$width =$_REQUEST['width'];

$parameter = $binary;

//Send parameter to application
exec("MyApp.exe test {$parameter} {$width}");
```

Comment: `The problem is when I send this variables`. Can you describe it (the problem)?

Comment: Looks about right, what is (not) happening?

Comment: Hang on, you are trying to pass the binary of an image as a command-line argument - that won't work. Pass the filename and read the file!

Comment: The problem is the variable width is not send and parameter send %PNG and that's all.

Comment: You are sending the complete image (binary data) as parameter? Shouldn`t your app just open the file test.jpg? the binary data may contain control-chars or is bigger than max arguments size.

Comment: To Mats Petersson : Yes it's a solution but I don't want to stock picture. In the php, it's just to verify there is no problem with the picture. At the end, I will delete the storage of picture.

Comment: I also find you should send $file but not $parametyer.

Comment: Yes but I lost time to stock a picture.

Comment: For security and reliability, you should also use an absolute path to the program and not just the name itself. Using the full path ensures that the program will be found regardless of the search path, and reduces the chance that (for example) a hacker who has some access to your system is able to create a trojan of the same name that is found in preference to the intended program.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are sending the binary data as your command line, since the only part of a PNG binary is the tag at the front of it, this is all that will be sent.

you want to run

```
$parameter = "test.jpg";
exec("MyApp.exe test {$parameter} {$width}");
```

or, you would want to run:

```
$parameter = "test.jpg";
exec("MyApp.exe test {$image} {$width}");
```

so that you are passing the base64 encoded data, rather than raw binary.